# How to track multiple websites moving to one domain with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am managing multiple websites that will soon move to one domain with each respective market being contained in a sub-directory e.g www.example.com/uk/.

The current situation is that all markets have their own GA property. I was wondering what the implications would be in just leaving the current setup as is?

I imagine GA alerts will fire implying that GA tracking is 'missing' across the website. Or would it be recommended to set the cookiePath field for each respective in the analytics.js create command?

The requirement is that each market is to have their own GA property giving them more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

## Make translation table

```
function getPropertyId(){
    var propertyIDs = {
       'uk' : 'UA-24574-1',
       'de' : 'UA-32656-4',
       'fi' : 'UA-54544-6'
    };

    var fallBackId = "UA-Falback";

    var path = window.document.location.pathname.split("/");
    if(path[1]){

      var propID = propertyIDs[path[1]] ? propertyIDs[path[1]] : fallBackId;    
      return propID;

    }
    else {
       return fallBackId;
    }
}
```

## Use it when setting Property ID

```
ga('create', getPropertyId() , 'auto');
```

### Request URI

You can expect troubles with Request URI variable, because:

From comment:
*@GKyle Imagine, your current URL is mycompany.uk/page.html and new URL will be mycompany.com/uk/page.html. In old setup will be Requested URI /page.html in new /uk/page.html. There will be inconsistency if you will do nothing. But if you set up a filter removing /uk, etc..*

**Wonderful regex:** ^(/(uk|de|au|en)\b/?)(.*)

From here: [RegExp - remove /en or /de from pathname string and return rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383491/regexp-remove-en-or-de-from-pathname-string-and-return-rest)

Rewrite string is **/$A3**

### Create Advanced Filter

[image: Google Analytics RegExp]

And please, TEST IT BEFORE!

## Result

You can smoothly change tracking from multiple domains under one main domain if you keep setting Property ID.
Keep in mind possible changes in certain reports, specially path based reports.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain troubles with Request URI?

Comment: @GKyle Imagine, your current URL is mycompany.uk/page.html and new URL will be mycompany.com/uk/page.html. In old setup will be Requested URI /page.html in new /uk/page.html. There will be inconsistency if you will do nothing. But if you set up a filter removing /uk (Use some regex like ^\/+(uk|de|au) - I am not too skilled in RegEx, so I open another question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383491/regexp-remove-en-or-de-from-pathname-string-and-return-rest)

Comment: Fantastic point thank you. One last question then. Can you please explain how your hostname filter above helps solves this? As that is quite different from the solution in your comment.

Comment: @GKyle that imageis not too relevant for this case (it was for ilustration what filter I meant), I will update that image as soon as I will have correct RegExp.

Comment: @GKyle I updated my answer with new regex and new image for you