# RegExp - remove /en or /de from pathname string and return rest

Tags: regex

I would like to remove language shortcodes from window.location.pathname.

## Possible input strings

```
/delorean
/de/page.html
/en/page.html
/
/spaceman
/en/
/en
```

## Desired output strings

```
/delorean
/page.html
/page.html
/
/spaceman
/
/
```

## Current approach

```
(^\/(uk|de|au|en)\/{0,1})(.*)
```

I would like to use $3 to use the remaining string, but I am facing some problems.

It works for all tested string except those who begin with reserverd string like de|en|uk (delorean,deep_purple,encephalograph,ukraine). It returns lorean,ep_purple,cephalograph,raine.

How to fix it for those string?

Link to regex101.com
https://regex101.com/r/0GGzeg/1

Comment: Not sure but a word boundary may help - `^(\/(uk|de|au|en)\b\/?)(.*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is not working for strings like /delorean, it returns nothing.

Comment: Just get rid of the option not to have a second slash: Change `(^\/(uk|de|au|en)\/{0,1})(.*)` to `(^\/(uk|de|au|en)\/)(.*)` and it should work.

Comment: @Linuxios it has the wery same disadvantage like Wiktors example. There is an option, that language shortcode will not be present, so it have to work on common pathname like / or /delorean or /delorean/

Comment: Sorry Wiktor, you were right. Please accept my apology for my mistake. Your solution is correct. When I tested it before, it was not working. Maybe my fault in test environment configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you, just substitute with `/$3` 3rd capturing group with preceding `/`

```
^(\/(uk|de|au|en)\b\/?)(.*)
```

See working example https://regex101.com/r/0GGzeg/3

[image]

Comment: @Always Sunny Thank you! It seem it is very same like Wiktor commented, but I can not understand why it was not working before.